# Is a specific person responsible for the GATE in GATE: Thus the JSDF Fought There?

Tags: gate

I've had questions for the longest time on this. Why or who would create a gigantic portal between two worlds?

Comment: To be CLEAR: I'm fine with theories, but please don't straight up take those three pages from the manga and answer this. I want to hear what person other people think could have opened the GATE if it was opened by a person.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to explain more clearly what kind of answer you're looking for. It's not clear to me how the current answer falls short. Please note that on this site we have strict rules about questions that ask for speculation on things that haven't been revealed in official source material

Comment: Sorry, but please don't answer this anymore. It's turning speculatory, and I apologise for this. Sorry, Torisuda and Hatsune Volcanoid Miku.

Comment: @kudokikiran theories based off from the original work using it as evidence is what we consider good answers. if the answer is actually answered in the manga that's actually better because then there is a canon reason

Comment: It's fine if you think there's more to the situation than what was directly quoted in the current answer and want to know if there's other evidence in the series that upholds that, as long as you provide a decent reason why you think so—e.g. "Lord So-and-So keeps on hinting that the gate is connected to the Mystical Blah Blah People; what evidence is there to support this?". It's just not clear right now what your question actually is; it would appear to be answered by the current answer. But feel free to edit it and explain more so we can understand what you're looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Explained in the manga I believe (links to the full size images):

[image: page 1]
[image: page 2]
[image: page 3]
[image: another page]

Please tell me how to do boxes.

> The person who created the Hole was Hardy, the ones to come by and created the Gate to keep the Hole opened were the Empire's magicians.

Comment: I did read the manga, and I do know this. I'm more or less asking who, if there was a person involved, opened the GATE.

Comment: @kudokikiran Well, in that case wouldn't "that's just a coincidence" be enough? You're talking about this one particular "GATE" on the Alnus Hill after all.